# iOS background thread slow down when UI is idle

Tags: c#, ios, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.ios

**A bit of context first**

I have a Xamarin app that *essentially* streams video from a remote server. I have a background thread that loops like this (pseudo-code):

```
private void UpdateMethod()
{
    while (running)
    {
        bool success = WaitForUpdate();

        if (!success)
        {
            break;
        }

        Update update = GetUpdate();
        SendUpdateToConcurentQueue(update);
    }

    Disconnect();
}
```

I start the background thread like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(UpdateMethod);
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Start();
```

**The issue**

When I start the stream, everything is perfect. It's only after ~10 seconds of not interacting with the device that it becomes really slow. I've outputted the number of updates from the background thread, and they seem to come in a lot slower. I usually get around 2-6 updates to process per update (60fps). When it's super slow, I get 1 ever 6 update cycle.

One thing that puzzles me: When I pull down the iOS top bar menu, the updates go back up and the stream is suddenly back to normal speed. Update rate goes up for ~10 seconds and it goes back to lagging like crazy.

**What I've tried**

I tried to start a Dispatch queue with only this in it, like this:

```
DispatchQueue queue = new DispatchQueue("updateQueue");
queue.DispatchAsync(this.UpdateProcess);
```

It didn't seem to help at all.

I also tried to change the QualityOfService property in my update thread like this:

```
NSThread.Current.QualityOfService = NSQualityOfService.UserInitiated
```

Doesn't work either! It seems to me that iOS lowers my thread's priority for some reason. If I put a breakpoint in my `UpdateMethod` method, it's being hit when the app doesn't lag. But when there's lag, the breakpoint doesn't get hit. Now this really puzzles me, since the code still runs! I still receive the updates, it's just way slower...

Edit: I tested using Instruments and found that the network is being throttled... Investigating, but if anyone has knowledge of any kind of network throttle on iOS, let me know.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the `IdleTimerDisabled` to `true`, we do this all the time in iOS games to keep iOS from idling our games.

Note: We do this in a `polite way` only when the user is not touching the screen due to watching a replay, level changing multimedia segues, etc...

Note: Make sure that you do reset the idle when you do not need it (when you app does go in the background, etc...), as from killing battery and making users bummed out about your app to the real killer: **Apple Store rejections**

Apple: [App Idle Timer info](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW56)

Xamarin: [UIKit.UIApplication.IdleTimerDisabled Property](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/UIKit.UIApplication.IdleTimerDisabled/)

> The default value of this property is NO. When most apps have no touches as user input for a short period, the system puts the device into a "sleep” state where the screen dims. This is done for the purposes of conserving power. However, apps that don't have user input except for the accelerometer—games, for instance—can, by setting this property to YES, disable the “idle timer” to avert system sleep.
>
> | IMPORTANT
>
> You should set this property only if necessary and should be sure to reset it to NO when the need no longer exists. Most apps should let the system turn off the screen when the idle timer elapses. This includes audio apps. With appropriate use of Audio Session Services, playback and recording proceed uninterrupted when the screen turns off. **The only apps that should disable the idle timer are mapping apps, games, or programs where the app needs to continue displaying content when user interaction is minimal.**

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've tried this too... But I'll give it another try. It seems though this is for the screen dimming, which doesn't appear to be happening only after 10 seconds.

Comment: I just tested it... still lagging :(

Comment: @PhilippeParé Physical Device or Simulator? Cellular (3g/4g/lte)? Wifi?

Comment: any physical device, wifi.

Comment: @PhilippeParé "Assuming" on the simulator you are not seeing this behavior(?)

Comment: @PhilippeParé What part is doing the actual network streaming, Xamarin/C# or your native lib? Using posix sockets with a circular packet queue... tcp/udp based?..

Comment: A native library, it does use posix sockets, tcp.

Comment: is there some sort of network throttling for an application when it's considered "idle"?

Comment: @PhilippeParé are you sure it is only iOS related issue, your logic works well on desktop or other device? Also delay may be inside your background thread logic, your queues or your data may be growing in size resulting in poor algorithm performance which has nothing to do with iOS?

Comment: @AkashKava yes, I use the same code for the android version and it works without problem